# Redirecting User to New Webpage that Starts Download Automatically in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, download

I have a wordpress website.When a user clicks on a Button the download starts as the button is linked to a file.Now i need a way to redirect the user to a new page with some information and start the download automatically.

What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this.

First pass file by URL

```
<a href="download.php?url=file.txt">Download</a>
```

Delay download for few seconds and run the url in page **download.php**

Like:

```
$file = $_GET['url'];
echo 'Your download is srarting...';
sleep(5);
header('location: '.$file);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But when a user clicks on the download button he will be redirected to www.mysite.com/info .. should i add the php code using the wordpress designer used for designing the webpage?